# NodeJS - Expiration on posts

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, cron

I'm building a website using MEAN stack. A user will post an item (and it will be stored to MongoDB) and I want to implement an expiry on that post. For example, they choose 7 days, after 7 days the user's post will be closed. How can I achieve that? It's like it will run a function to close the post based on how long the user sets it. I can't imagine how will I achieve it.

How can I implement something that will automatically close the post of a user based on the days they set?

Comment: https://www.ekito.fr/people/auto-expire-documents-mongodb-collections/

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/

Comment: thanks man! i'll check it out!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Node Cron**, it is a Node package that allows you to schedule tasks.

In this case, you could check every day if each post was created more than 7 days ago (or the time expiration the user set), and if it is, delete it.

This is the **package repo** with the documentation of how to use it:

[Node Cron by merencia](https://github.com/merencia/node-cron)

I hope it helps you!

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a MEAN App and also have the `MongoDB` in place, I would suggest you to go for **Agenda** which has a Mongo backed persistance layer, it is also very lightweight compared to **Node Cron**, Furthermore it offers web-interfaces to monitor the task progress.

You can explore more here,

**NPM Registry page:**
https://www.npmjs.com/package/agenda

**GitHub page:** https://github.com/rschmukler/agenda

Hope this helps!